# roboblender-3.0.1.jar: not included in Android: javax.tools. Referenced from com.google.inject.blender.AnnotationDatabaseGenerator

Tags: android, proxy, gradle, vpn, roboguice

I try to build my android project and I get:

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [clean, :app:compileDebugSources]
Information:1/10/15, 11:13 AM - Compilation completed successfully in 5 sec
```

I then try to deploy it to my device and get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
```

I then look at the lint report and see:

```
InvalidPackage: Package not included in Android
../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.roboguice/roboblender/3.0.1/d629079b9bfa8d889ec833d1eb747e89cf789bfa/roboblender-3.0.1.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.tools. Referenced from com.google.inject.blender.AnnotationDatabaseGenerator.
../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.roboguice/roboguice/3.0.1/24e814f35d5cc28eaa7e9f07a50ea69deeb2b544/roboguice-3.0.1.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.inject. Referenced from com.google.inject.Scopes.3.
../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/2ceb567b8f3f21118ecdec129fe1271dbc09aa7a/velocity-1.7.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.naming. Referenced from org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.DataSourceResourceLoader.
../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/2ceb567b8f3f21118ecdec129fe1271dbc09aa7a/velocity-1.7.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.servlet.http. Referenced from org.apache.velocity.servlet.VelocityServlet.
../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/2ceb567b8f3f21118ecdec129fe1271dbc09aa7a/velocity-1.7.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.servlet. Referenced from org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.ServletLogChute.
```

I work on mac and roboguice used to work till last night.

I have VPN proxy as it's my job mac. I tried to turn it off and on. nothing helped.

I usually surf the net successfully without it.

what can go wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding lint options to your project's build.gradle file.

```
 android {
  // your build config
  defaultConfig { ... }
  signingConfigs { ... }
  compileOptions { ... }
  buildTypes { ... }
  // This is important, it will run lint checks but won't abort build
  lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }
}
```

if this didn't work try replacing it with

```
android {
  // your build config
  defaultConfig { ... }
  signingConfigs { ... }
  compileOptions { ... }
  buildTypes { ... }
  // This is important, it will run lint checks but won't abort build
  lintOptions {
      checkReleaseBuilds false
  }
}
```